# How to 'package' request parms into one object

Tags: spring-mvc

If you have a controller method which has a whole bunch of parameters such as:

```
getSomething (String a, int b, Timestamp c, etc...)
```

what is the best way to replace those with an object, so you do not have to then instantiate a new object and set all those from the parameters, like so:

```
SomeObject o = new SomeObject();
o.setA(a);
o.setB(b);
o.setC(c);
etc..
// use o on other method calls to prepare a response
```

I have tried @ModelAttribute like so:

```
getSomething (@modelAttribute SomeObject o)
```

but it does not seem to work well unless you only use simple types for properties such as strings and ints. A Timestamp property for example causes it to fail with a "Bad Request"

@RequestBody could work, but with some pretty significant changes required to your method call which ends up that you can no longer simply call that method by the browser anymore to test it, which makes development much more annoying.

Is there no way to tell Spring to accept a bunch of parameters in a regular http GET request and use them to instantiate an object for you with the ability to work with all property data types?

Comment: SomeObject is a simple POJO which you can use (just like you said) as ModelAttribute. You can use Spring's FORM tag and supply this as your model for your form. Then map your form input fields to your instance variables in your POJO.

Comment: The Timestamp instance variable you can set in your POJO right? It does not have to be on the HTML/Spring form itself.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to write a type converter for the Timestamp class, and register it with Spring MVC ConversionService.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Why can't you use a Date or DateTime (Joda Time) class?

Make sure you use the @Timestamp annotation if using JPA

Comment: Using Date is truncating all time components. I never heard of DateTime and my IDE does not recognize it either.

Comment: @Trant it's truncating them in memory or in the database?